# Hashmap is not able to count all the occurence

Tags: java, hashmap, reduce

Hashmap is not able to count all the occurence.

This is a sample code from Hadoop Reduce().

My mapper out key and values are

```
key---------6.9
v---------------Iris-versicolor
v---------------Iris-virginica
v---------------Iris-virginica
v---------------Iris-versicolor
v---------------Iris-virginica
v---------------Iris-virginica
v---------------Iris-virginica
v---------------Iris-virginica
v---------------Iris-virginica
v---------------Iris-virginica
v---------------Iris-versicolor
v---------------Iris-virginica
v---------------Iris-versicolor
v---------------Iris-versicolor
v---------------Iris-virginica
```

My expected result is

```
getVal-----------{Iris-versicolor=5, Iris-virginica=10}
```

But I am getting the output as

```
getVal-----------{Iris-versicolor=1, Iris-virginica=2}
```

Sofar what I did is

```
System.out.println("key---------"+key);
for(Text val:values){
    String v = val.toString();
    System.out.println("v---------------"+v);
    if (getVal.isEmpty()) {
        getVal.put(v, 1);
    } 
    else {
        for (String colId : getVal.keySet()) {
        if(colId.equals(v)){
            Integer val1 = getVal.get(colId);
            val1 = val1 + 1;
            getVal.put(colId, val1);
        }
        else{
            getVal.put(v, 1);
        }

    }

    }
}
System.out.println("getVal-----------"+getVal);
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: No there is no whitespaces

Comment: Downvoters pls comment so that I can improve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the else clause
2. Add the value to the map if it is not present - not when the map is empty!

Example:

```
System.out.println( "key---------" + key );

for ( String value : values ) {

  // I used `String` instead of your `Text` type
  // so I do not need this line
  // String v = value.toString();

  System.out.println( "v---------------" + value );

  // if the value is not present, add it!
  // each value will be added once!
  if ( !valueCounterMap.containsKey( value ) )
    valueCounterMap.put( value, 1 );

  // if the value is already present, just 
  // increment its counter by 1
  else {

      Integer counter = valueCounterMap.get( value );
      valueCounterMap.put( value, ++counter );
  }
}

System.out.println( "getVal-----------" + valueCounterMap );
```

Result:

```
getVal-----------{Iris-versicolor=5, Iris-virginica=10}
```